# Easy Mock and power mock no last call on a mock avaliable

Tags: java, junit, mocking

I am getting the above no last call on a mock available exception when running java junits.  Below is my Junit.

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({Dao.class})
public class test {

    //create services and parameters to mock.       
    Dao dataAccessObject;   

    /**
     * Testing the displaySOLQDetailPage_xa() method with Mockito.
     */
    @Test
    public void testPostConversationExtension() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        System.out.println("dfasdfasd");
        this.dataAccessObject = PowerMockito.mock(Dao.class);
        List <Beans> testResults = new ArrayList<Beans>();
        EasyMock.expect(dataAccessObject.getSource("", true)).andReturn(testResults);
        PowerMock.replayAll();
        PowerMock.verifyAll();      
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You mocked `dataAccessObject` using PowerMockito, which extends Mockito functionality, but doesn't work with EasyMock.
That's why `EasyMock.expect()` method doesn't recognize `dataAccessObject` as a mock.
Use PowerMock instead - replace

```
PowerMockito.mock(Dao.class);
```

with

```
PowerMock.createMock(Dao.class);
```